# Common diversification strategy for bond investment?

Tags: investing, bonds

What is the most common diversification strategy for bond investment for a long term investor?

- long vs. intermediate vs short term
- inflation protected (TIPS)
- US vs world
- government vs corporate
  etc.

There is plenty of into on stock allocation, but not that much for bonds.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. The answer depends on risk tolerance, location, taxes, and other factors. A quick Google search turned up this result, as an introduction: https://www.schwab.com/resource-center/insights/content/the-elements-of-a-diversified-bond-portfolio

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD That's a really usefull link, with a concrete allocation example I can use as a starting point - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

The big-name active bond funds are just active but most likely they are intermediate. But an intermediate bond fund can shorten its duration with hedging.

A closed-end bond fund will likely use more leverage and hedging than an open-end fund but there are some big-name active open-end funds.

Comment: Well, an active bond fund responds to macro-economic trends and that is its diversification strategy. A diversification formula, on the other hand, would make an index.